# filtering data and working with scales - d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a simple scatterplot in d3js. The aim of the visualization is to fade out points on a selection. This works. Congruent with this, a new trendline should appear only for those selected points as well as an updated slope equation and R2 value.  The fading of points and updating of slope equation/R2 values is working on selection.  However, the trendline appears to be truncated and not scaled correctly, but I can't figure out why.

[Here is a working version.](http://blockbuilder.org/jalapic/18b997f9b1025b21470d058b918421b9)

Following the `on.change` the following code is executed:

```
filteredData  = filterJSON(data, 'name', value); // gets filtered json data

  var x = d3.scaleLinear()
      .range([0,width]);

  var y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .range([height,0]);


  var xSeries1 = filteredData.map(function(e) { return e.x; }); // new x values
  var ySeries1 = filteredData.map(function(e) { return e.y; }); // new y values
  var rsq1 = leastSquares(xSeries1,ySeries1); // calculates r2/slope etc. - see function below

 // Add trendline
  ptAx1 =  d3.min(xSeries1);
  ptAy1 =  rsq1[0] *  d3.min(xSeries1) + rsq1[1];
  ptBy1 =  d3.min(ySeries1);
  ptBx1 =  (d3.min(ySeries1) - rsq1[1]) / rsq1[0];



  svg.append("line")
        .attr("class", "regression")
        .attr("x1", x(ptAx1))   
        .attr("y1", y(ptAy1))
        .attr("x2", x(ptBx1))
        .attr("y2", y(ptBy1));




// calculate linear regression
function leastSquares(xSeries,ySeries) {

  var reduceSumFunc = function(prev, cur) { return prev + cur; };

  var xBar = xSeries.reduce(reduceSumFunc) * 1.0 / xSeries.length;
  var yBar = ySeries.reduce(reduceSumFunc) * 1.0 / ySeries.length;

  var ssXX = xSeries.map(function(d) { return Math.pow(d - xBar, 2); })
    .reduce(reduceSumFunc);

  var ssYY = ySeries.map(function(d) { return Math.pow(d - yBar, 2); })
    .reduce(reduceSumFunc);

  var ssXY = xSeries.map(function(d, i) { return (d - xBar) * (ySeries[i] - yBar); })
    .reduce(reduceSumFunc);

  var slope = ssXY / ssXX;
  var intercept = yBar - (xBar * slope);
  var rSquare = Math.pow(ssXY, 2) / (ssXX * ssYY);

  return [slope, intercept, rSquare];
}
```

This code works well when all data points (no filtering of data), but doesn't when filtering occurs.

This is all points - trendline ok
[image]

This is filtered points - trendline truncated
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you left "min" where you meant "max" in assigning values to ptBy1 and ptBx1

Made this change in your "blockbuilder" and it seemed to work as intended.